# Parse javascript returned value-object from Android app

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm calling a JavaScript function from my application's WebView. 
This function returns (if i call it from firebug) for example:

Object {top: 350.171875, left: 129.265625, w: 311, h: 115}

What i want is to get the values of top, left, w and h from my Android application.
But when I try to get the values through WebChromeClient onJsAlert() method the value
of message parameter is [object Object]. Is there a way to extract the required values of top, left, w, h from [object Object]? i can't find a way to parse [object Object].

Comment: you need to bind a javascriptinterface to your webview

Comment: Isn't enough something like that? myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:someJsFunction()");

Comment: this will call the javascript function, but you will not be able to get the return value of the function. You need a callback in java with a javascriptinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you can use a JavascriptInterface (see http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

This can be your callback interface:

```
public class MyInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void myCallback(int top, int left, int w, int h) {
        // This is where you receive the values
    }
}
```

This is how you bind it:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyInterface(), "Android");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:someJsFunction()");
```

And this is is how you javascript sends the values :

```
function someJsFunction() {
    Android.myCallback(dimensions.top, dimensions.left, dimensions.w, dimensions.h);
}
```

You cannot pass an actual object from javascript to android. You can only pass primitives, strings, and arrays of these.

Comment: So, if someone has no access to the javascript function to edit it and add as a return value Android.myCallback(...), there is no other way to pass the javascript object to Android.

Comment: you can use an eval to pass new javascript to the currently executed : `javascript:eval('Android:myCallback(...)')`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply do `dimensions.top` or `dimensions.left`, etc (Assuming the object is stored in the variable `dimensions`)

```
var dimensions = {top: 350.171875, left: 129.265625, w: 311, h: 115}; //Would actually be a call to your function to calculate these dimensions
alert(dimensions.top);
```